# Simulating non-linear ARX model doesn't work

Tags: matlab, simulation, non-linear, system-identification

I estimated a non-linear ARX model with the sytem identification toolbox in matlab and tried to simulate the response to a validation data set. Unfortunatly the response seems to be not stable and doesn't lead to the results obtained from the compare fcn.

nlarx2 is my model:

`opt3=simOptions("InputOffset",4,"InitialCondition",IO); sim(nlarx2,Data_val1.InputData,opt3)`

The initial condition is obtained from the estimation data set from the compare fcn

I dont know if I have to add the discretness of the model or what else could be wrong. The error message says:

">> sim(nlarx2,Data_val1.InputData,opt3)
Warning: Model output became non-finite at time 58 seconds. Aborting the rest of the simulation.

> In idnlarx/utsim>localInfNanWarn (line 79)
> In idnlarx/utsim (line 61)
> In idnlarx/sim_ (line 129)
> In idmodel/sim (line 113) "

I obtain a figure, but not a useful one.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I found a simple solution for the problem. I used the command findStates to obtain my initial conditions.   'IO = findstates(nlarx,Data_estimation,inf); ' For that I just used the estimation Data set I took to estimate my non-linear ARX model in the first place.